# Find the lim inf and lim sup of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Q 1:      $a_n= sin⁡(\frac{n\pi}2) +  \frac{(-1)^n}n, \ n \in \mathbb N$, show that , $\liminf a_n=-1$ and $\limsup a_n= 1$.

This sequence is bounded. I have found the upper and the lower bound i.e.
lower bound $= -\frac 43$
and upper bound= 1
 i am not able to solve it further , in an appropriate manner

Comment: Your notation is peculiar. Can you convert to normal notation?

Comment: it is normal sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will split n into even and odd components, because n being even or odd creates different patterns for $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$ and notice also if n is odd, $(-1)^n=-1$ and if n is even, $(-1)^n=1$. This means it makes a lot of sense to seperate these two ideas.

If $n$ is even, your equation becomes $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}$$
{since $\sin(k\pi)=0$  $\forall k\in\Bbb Z$}

For which the limit is $0$.

If we take n to be odd on the other hand, the scene changes quite a bit. To see the variance I will split the odd integers into two groups, those of the form $4k+1$ and those of the form $4k+3$.

This is because $\sin((\frac{4k+1}{2})\pi)=1$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$ (whole numbers) and $\sin((\frac{4k+3}{2})\pi)=-1$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$ 
See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7gkcwwsibo and https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h7ubnpte1g to see this graphed, just check the value of the graph wherever $x$ is a whole number.

If $n=4k+1$, we get:

$$a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$$
We're happy that the limit of $\frac{1}{n}$ is $0$, so this limit is $1-0=1$.

If $n=4k+3$, we get:
$$a_n=-1-\frac{1}{n}$$
For which it follows that the limit is $-1$. 
Hence the superior(greater) limit is $1$, and the inferior (lower) limit is $-1$ as stated in your question.

Comment: Sir can you please explain the necessity to consider this equation into even and odd. And please explain how on putting n=4k+1 we would get 1-1/n

Comment: Sure thing. I'll just edit my answer to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Has been edited... is it clear now?

Comment: thankyou sir. It is now very much clear :D

Comment: I was very much confused , but now i am cleared :D